# kubectl not getting all pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, google-cloud-shell

I am using Google Cloud Platform, and I have two different kubernetes clusters running on GKE. Now these clusters are zonal clusters, and are running on different zones. the issue is when I am using the cloud shell, `kubectl get pods` is getting pods from another cluster. I have used `kubectl config set-cluster xxx` to set the cluster, but still, the other pods are showing only.

Comment: Can you provide the output of kubectl config view?

Comment: I can't really do that, but the very weird thing is, other clusters have the following properties : name, server, and certificate-authority-data. but the cluster that I want to have its pods showing, only has name and server, where the server is empty, and the name showing just the cluster name ex : my_test_cluster. where as the others show like : gke_projectname_zone_cluster-name

Comment: @A.Darwin thank you for your answer, but the above comment still puzzles me and I don't thing it qualifies to be a full post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `kubectl get pods` returns pods from another cluster, your kubectl configuration is probably pointing to the other cluster.

You can check the current context (current cluster) kubectl is using with: `kubectl config current-context`.

Note that, [as the GKE documentation highlights](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl):

> When you create a cluster using the Google Cloud console or using gcloud CLI from a different computer, your environment's kubeconfig file is not updated. Additionally, if a project team member uses gcloud CLI to create a cluster from their computer, their kubeconfig is updated but yours is not. The kubeconfig entry contains either:

> Your credentials as shown in gcloud auth list, or

> The application default credentials, if configured.

> To generate a kubeconfig context in your environment, ensure that you have the container.clusters.get permission. The least-privileged IAM role that provides this permission is container.clusterViewer.

> To generate a kubeconfig context for a specific cluster, run the following command:

> `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME`

> Replace CLUSTER_NAME with the name of your cluster.

> If the target cluster is not running in the default zone or region, or if you did not set a default zone or region, you need to supply the region (--region=REGION) or zone (--zone=ZONE) in the command.

> Note: Running gcloud container clusters get-credentials also changes the current context for kubectl to that cluster.